# How do I achieve Azure Cosmos DB item TTL from creation time?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, ttl

We want to keep certain documents in our DB for a short duration. When a document is created, it doesn't matter how often its modified but it should be deleted after say X time units.

We looked at [time to live in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/time-to-live) but it seems to set the TTL from last edit and not creation.

One approach that we are considering is reduce the TTL everytime we update based on current time vs last update time of the document. It is hacky and inaccurate to errors due to clock skews.

Is there a better/accurate approach to achieving expiry from creation time? Our next approach will be to setup a service bus event that will trigger document deletion. Even that is more of best effort approach than an accurate TTL.

Comment: You're correct that TTL in Cosmos DB is based on modification time, so it's reset every time you modify a document. You'd need to come up with your own scheme if that didn't work for you (such as running a periodic job, comparing a creation timestamp to current time, deleting if past that time duration...). There's nothing built-in to do TTL removal based on creation date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you update a record you can derive a new TTL from the current TTL and the _ts field. So first get the item, derive the new TTL, and update the item together with the new (smaller) TTL.

Comment: This is indeed what we had ended up doing.